# Open source rules engine with decent interface for writing rules

Tags: .net, rule-engine

I'm trying to locate an open source business rules engine that has a decent interface for building the rules.

OR at least one that works well on the .Net platform and has been updated sometime in the past 12 months.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NxBRE is one option.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nxbre/#item3rd-5

Answer (score 1):

[.NET Application Block for Validation and Business Rules](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/11/23/net-application-block-for-validation-and-business-rules.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reaction RuleML. The Rule Manager from Acumen Business has an adapter for business users to generate a valid [RuleML document](http://2007.ruleml.org/docs/Acumen%20Business%20-%20RuleML.pdf)

Comment: @BozoJoe: The information on their site looks good, but I can't figure out how much it is, whether they have an open source version, or even how I'd go about buying it.  I think they really need to work on their site.

Comment: Chris, the RuleML adapter is free (but not open source). Only the Biztalk Adapter and Windows Workflow Adapter need a license. I was trying to make the adapter module open source. But got stuck in a .net 4.0 upgrade. That triggered so many changes that the next release is taking much longer. The 4.0 was required to interface with BizTalk 2010 :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw one more piece of software I ran across: [ncalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

It's not exactly a "rules" engine; but it does do dynamic calculations where you can give it the expression to evaluate and all of the variables necessary.   This was pretty much exactly all I needed for the app I was working on.

For a simple engine it works just fine.  As far as an interface, it wasn't that complicated to build a few pages to let people type in the expressions.

For more complicated things, NxBRE is a better option; as @Kevin Dente answered above.

Answer (score 0):

Modern alternatives seem to be:

- Microsoft's [own RuleEngine](https://microsoft.github.io/RulesEngine/), which seems to be built upon a JSON rule definition including third-party (wed) editors
- [NRules](https://nrules.net/) seems to be flexible and powerful, but JSON serialization [is only possible through a module](https://yunier.dev/post/2023/rule-engines-in-dotnet/) and looks, from a first glance, less readable than RuleEngine

[Here is a blog post comparing these, including comparing to a self-written RuleEngine.](https://yunier.dev/post/2023/rule-engines-in-dotnet/)

([copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78106851/15488899))