# Example of c# based rule language?

Tags: c#, rule-engine

Can you provide a good example of rule definition language written in C#.
Java guys have [JESS](http://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/), is there anything good for C#?

Comment: This article can help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/buisness-rules-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This page shows some examples of open-source rules engines in C#: http://csharp-source.net/open-source/rule-engines

Answer (score 2):

You can use the forward chaining inference engine that is part of Windows Workflow Foundation (.NET 3.5 and higher) The best part is that this has a free runtime licensing.

You can use the [Rule Manager](http://www.acumenbusiness.com/products.htm) from Acumen Business and install the Windows Workflow Foundation adapter. Once installed, export the rules as WFRules (*.rules). 
A visual studio .NET solution will be generated that shows how the rule engine can be invoked standalone (no workflow is necessary)

See also http://bizknowledge.blogspot.com/search/label/Windows%20Workflow%20Foundation

Answer (score 2):

Try http://rulesengine.codeplex.com
It has a fluent-interface wrapper for creating rules.
It's lightweight and simple to use.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a rules engine IMO.  It's more like a validation engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx)'s (WF) workflow engine with C#.  I'd started a small and simple project using WF as the workflow engine, it's actually quite straightforward to use.  Check out the first part entry I've been developing on this [here](http://www.sanderstechnology.com/?p=10166).

What is interesting about WF is that you don't have to use the whole thing if you want to - if you only want to write some custom rules against some entities or objects, you can - quite ingenious!  Also, it's a lot less to take on board than BizTalk's BRE (and no licensing cost).

You need to add a reference to the following .Net assemblies, available in the .Net Framework v3.0 and onwards:

- System.Workflow.Activities
- System.Workflow.ComponentModel
- System.Workflow.Runtime

Check out the article for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Microsoft Business Rules Engine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561216.aspx. Not sure if it can only be used inside Biztalk - it does says it is a .Net Class Library.

Comment: It can be used outside BizTalk, but you need a valid BizTalk License.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Business Rule Engine(BRE) is quite nice. But(and that's a big BUT) you'll need a BizTalk Server license to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jetfire on codeplex](http://jetfire.codeplex.com/).   It supports forward chaining '[rules](http://wiki.jetfire.ca/Rules.ashx)'.

Answer (score 0):

Modern alternatives seem to be:

- Microsoft's [own RuleEngine](https://microsoft.github.io/RulesEngine/), which seems to be built upon a JSON rule definition including third-party (wed) editors
- [NRules](https://nrules.net/) seems to be flexible and powerful, but JSON serialization [is only possible through a module](https://yunier.dev/post/2023/rule-engines-in-dotnet/) and looks, from a first glance, less readable than RuleEngine

[Here is a blog post comparing these, including comparing to a self-written RuleEngine.](https://yunier.dev/post/2023/rule-engines-in-dotnet/)

[(same as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78107432/15488899))