# Inference engine for a recommender platform

Tags: asp.net, database, rule-engine

I'm looking for some advice on a project I'm currently working on. I need to match some user input (criteria) with entries in a database. I think I should probably use a rule engine to evaluate the input as a set of propositions against its knowledge base, that in this case ought to be the database itself. The project is being developed in ASP.NET and I'd like to know if I'm on the right path. Should I try something like Windows Workflow Foundation rules engine or NxBRE to accomplish this goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can try the WWF rule engine.Also check out the IBM ILOG Jrules for .net technologies.Its gaining some popularity nowadays. As you are working in .net platform,cant recommend Drools,though it is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks! Now that you mention Drools, can you tell me if Drools.NET (which is based on JBoss rules) is a viable option? I don't know if the project is still active, nor if it has even been 'widely' used.

Comment: Drools .net is not under development now.the. last release was 2007.so not recommended.if your requirement is simple..u can go with other rule engines.the ones I mentioned are enterprise level.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, a simple rules engine could do the trick. Can you recommend me one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766/open-source-rules-engine-with-decent-interface-for-writing-rules